# iOS Devices do not show up on Xcode 6.1.1 - until after rebooting the Mac

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, osx-yosemite

Since updating to Xcode 6.1 all of my iOS devices will not be recognized by the Mac after a period of time. It used to be every couple of days, but now it is happening several times a day.

The only remedy is to reboot the Mac. This is completely unacceptable and counter to any UNIX based OS. I have run this same Mac for months before installing Yosemite, without issue.

The only clue is in the System logs:

```
12/22/14 8:42:53.681 PM Xcode[385]: AMDeviceConnect (thread 0x128e11000): Could not connect to lockdown port (62078) on device 67 - 28cb21671799bc4efe266987ae586ba2cb6247b7: 0xe8000084.
```

I have scoured the web for weeks and even filed a radar. I know that other devs have experienced this ridiculous behavior. Does anyone have a idea what is going on or what service is failing?

Currently running OS X 10.10.1, Xcode 6.1.1 and issues occur with iOS 8.1.2, iOS 8.1 and iOS 7.1.2

Comment: Found a possible similar solution/symptom here http://andyaffleck.com/tag/itunes/ - I have emptied my /var/db/lockdown folder and reconnected devices. The need to "Trust" the Mac every time I connect seems to be gone. I will keep an eye on this and see if the problem settles down.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I've been having this issue for over a month now.  It's not just Xcode but also iTunes, Image Capture, and some other apps that should easily see my devices.  I also often get the "trust this computer?" query, but not every time that the Mac starts rejecting my devices.

Instead of restarting the Mac, the other option is to quit Xcode, issue the following command in Terminal:

> sudo launchctl stop com.apple.usbmuxd

and then restart Xcode

Comment: Cool. I will give that a try. I figured there had to be a better way than rebooting. I haven't had the problem crop up since I cleaned out /var/db/lockdown. I suspect it was related to permissions issues not being set right during the upgrade to Yosemite. I also had 5 years worth of profiles it the directory, with varying permissions.

Comment: After submitting my app to the AppStore, Xcode_6.1 didn't recognize any iDevices with iOS-6 or iOS-7 !?? Only iDevices with iOS-8 could be used! Was about to pull my remaining hear out of my head, but luckily restarting my Mac did solve this problem! The above sudo-command did not work, but the restart tip saved my day, thanks!

Comment: Worked for me, Xcode 6.1 and iOS 8.1 , iPhone 4S (y)

Comment: It also worked for me for Xcode 7.2 and iPhone OS 9.2. Thanks buddy!

Comment: @mahboudz thx buddy! it works! may i ask how to came about the solution? I want to get a general idea of how to solve this kind of problem when I encounter it next time. cheers

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why this bug happens, but after searching a lot about it I got a simple but effective solution.

When the problem starts, I tried to restart my machine, re-install Xcode and Command Line tools without results, and after googling about it, I saw that you can fix it removing `lockdown` folder using the command below and restarting.

```
sudo rm -rf /var/db/lockdown
sudo mkdir /var/db/lockdown
sudo chmod go+w /var/db/lockdown
```

It works for some users so I will leave it here, but in my case it not helped.

As @mahboudz said, you can trigger the command below from terminal with Xcode closed, without restarting the machine.

```
sudo launchctl stop com.apple.usbmuxd
```

This time, my problem was gone, until I turn my Mac next day. The problem came back again. I can resolve it again temporary using the command above, but it will happen again and again on every launch.

Knowing the problem is related with `com.apple.usbmuxd`, I saw on some threads that this process is not only related with Xcode, but USB <-> iPhone device communication.

I fix my problem definitely simply **downloading and installing iTunes again** after stopping `com.apple.usbmuxd` process.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 6.3 with my iPad, I've found that rebooting the iPad works without having to close Xcode.

Answer (score -1):

Top to your Right Click on 
**Window > Devices**

You will see that no devices will be showing
Do the following
**Bottom Left** 
**Click on the +** 
And then start adding your devices.

Comment: This allows the creation of new simulator profiles, it does nothing with actual connected devices.