# iOS Device not showing for iOS 8.2 and Xcode 6.2

Tags: ios, xcode

Despite this:

[iOS Devices do not show up on Xcode 6.1.1 - until after rebooting the Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27613083/ios-devices-do-not-show-up-on-xcode-6-1-1-until-after-rebooting-the-mac)

and restarting my Mac, replugging my iOS device I cannot see my iOS device in Xcode.

Any further suggestions?

Comment: Try reistalling xcode...

Comment: What is the version of iOS on your device?

Comment: @Eimantas I mentioned this in the question - iOS8.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Does your device appears in iTunes ?**
if it doesn't show make sure you trusted your mac from your device.
if it shows, try quitting your Xcode entirely and replugging your device into deferent port then open Xcode again.
if problem still persists you will have to reinstall your Xcode

Comment: This led me to the correct answer so I'm going to accept it. Embarrassingly, I'd bent the connector to the phone. Unplugging it and replugging it upside down fixed the problem. I gave it a slight tweak and blew any dust out off the connector to be doubly-sure and now it all works. So, the moral of the story is - before you start checking all the software - just see if your device: 1. charges and 2. shows up in iTunes!